# REST convention for parent insert and parent + joinId insert using same endpoint

Tags: rest, uri, naming-conventions

In context of an event management system where speakers are talking at different sessions. My entities are Speakers and Sessions

Let's say the endpoint is

1) `POST /speakers` (to insert detail of a speaker ONLY)

2) `POST /speakers` (to insert detail of speaker + id of the session he's talking on)

point 2 requires to do an additional insert in the join table.

How can I specify both kinds of operations within the same endpoint.

Comment: @LutzHorn please comment or answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A speaker could be represented including the session he speaks on. For example:

```
{
  "id": 1234,
  "firstname": "Joe",
  "lastname": "Doe",
  "sessions": []
}
```

This representation means that the speaker **is not speaking on any session**. `sessions` is an empty array. Doing

```
POST /speakers
Content-Type: application/json
```

with the JSON body as show above, would *create the speaker*.

If the client **knows in advance all sessions the speaker will be speaking**, the JSON could look like this:

```
{
  "id": 1234,
  "firstname": "Joe",
  "lastname": "Doe",
  "sessions": [
    {
      "id": 12,
      "link": "/session/12"
    },
    {
      "id": 34,
      "link"; "/session/34"
    }
  ]
}
```

For each session the speaker is speaking on, a short object consisting only of the `id` and a  `link` to the session are included. This should be enough for the server to know how to link speaker and sessions in the database.

Now let's consider the case, that the sessions a speaker will speak on are *not* known in advance by the client. The client would create the speaker using the first JSON representation above including an empty `sessions` array. Later, **when all sessions the speaker will speak on are known to the client**, he would make a `PATCH` request:

```
PATCH /speakers/1234
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "sessions": [
    {
      "id": 12,
      "link": "/session/12"
    },
    {
      "id": 34,
      "link"; "/session/34"
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that now we only send the `sessions`. All other attributes of the speaker shall be left as is on the server.

If the client wants to **add sessions to the speaker** one after the other, he could do this for every session:

```
POST /speakers/1234/sessions
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "id": 43,
  "link": "/sessions/43"
}
```

This would mean: "add session 43 to the list of sessions of speaker 1234". here `/speakers/1234/sessions` is a *sub resource* of `/speaker/1234`. Adding to it makes sense (of course the server would have to check for duplicates).

Note the different usage of `POST` to *create* a new resource (a speaker), to *add* to a sub resource (the list of sessions). Note also that *changing only part* of a resource (the speaker) uses `PATCH`.

**Edit:**

The HTTP verb `PUT` is usually used if the client wants to send the *complete* representation of a resource. When adding the list of sessions to an existing speaker, we use `PATCH` on the speaker because using `PUT` on him would require the client to send *a complete representation of the speaker*. In this use case the client does not want to do this, he wants to set the list of sessions.

An alternative way could be to

```
PUT /speakers/1234/sessions
Content-Type: application/json

[
  {
    "id": 12,
    "link": "/session/12"
  },
  {
    "id": 34,
    "link"; "/session/34"
  }
]
```

with a *complete list of sessions* on the *subresource* `sessions`. Note the difference: here the client is sending a complete representation of the list of sessions for the speaker. Here `PUT` means: "Overwrite the complete list of sessions for this speaker with what I provide".

Using `/speakers?eventId=1` to get the list of speakers for even `1` is good practice. Here the client requests a *filtered subset* of the collection resource `/speakers`. Using query parameter to express filter conditions is very common.

About good resources for this kind of knowledge my general advice is to always think about *resource*. What are the resources your API provides? How are different types of resources related? Can they exist next to each other (a speaker can exist without a session, a session can exist without a speaker), or are the composites (a hotel room can only exist inside a hotel). Usually this kind of question helps. But in REST there are no hard  rules or "standards" for how URLs *must* be constructed. I think it is important to be consistent in an API.

Comment: awesome, I feel good about using PATCH, a good use case. Can you please tell me why PUT in this case was not used and where it could be used instead.

Comment: Comment 2 -> Also I'm confused between these two, `/speakers?eventId=1` list of speakers for event 1, `/speakers` (all speakers), is it correct using query string or should be something different? because `/speakers/1` is reserved for detail of the speaker 1,

Comment: Also I'm finding it hard to learn this kind of knowledge over the internet, any book specifically for these kinds of problems can you refer to. I read the REST API Design Rulebook but it doesn't have this kind of information we are discussing here.

Comment: Thanks, I favorite this answer, any books that you can recommend to study in depth about this stuff.